I was working on this machine learning question and I dont seem to get how to solve it!

I have tried doing it so many ways, but none seem to work. I don't understand these LOOCV errors

Please type out your question. Screenshots are not accessible to vision-impaired readers, and so we try to avoid them here.

i'm totally stealing this great exam question

Consider the K-nearest neighbours approach using Euclidean distance on the
dataset shown in Figure 2. What are the LOOCV errors for the following cases?
Briefly justify your answers.
i. 1-nearest neighbour.
ii. 3-nearest neighbours. I have a test tomorrow and this is a sample question. I have the answer but I don't seem to understand the answer
